# JQuery - Autocomplete / smartSearch Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I want to get a autocomplete function like this: http://www.nationalrail.co.uk/default.aspx.

I want to provide full names as suggestions for the input-text like this

> Hannover (HAN)

But after selecting a suggested entry I want to set only the three letters instead of the full name like this

> HAN

I already tried [JQueryUI - Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) but there is no opportunity to differ between the suggested names and the values which will be set after selecting an entry.

I have an array like

```
[
  ["Hannover", "HAN"],
  ["Frankfurt", "FRA"],
  ...
]
```

Is there any package, module, framework which can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this code snippet...Hope that this will help you.

This will be your HTML content and the corresponding script is also given...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

The Script is Given Below

```
$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
```

Hope that this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need Label and Id. Label is for text search and Id is to store your code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var data = [
        {"id":"HAN","label":"Hannover [HAN]"},
        {"id":"FRA","label":"Frankfurt [FRA]"},
    ]
    $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
      source: data,
      select: function(event, ui) {
                $('#code').val(ui.item.id);
      },
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <input type="text" id="search">
  <input type="text" id="code"> <!-- change to type="hidden" -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```